# Use minted code for moodle questions

Tags: minted, incompatibility, moodle

I am a teacher for Computer Science, and I would like to use Moodle quizzes for coding questions. To do so I am experimenting with this code example for generating the question xml which I import into Moodle.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[nostamp]{moodle}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % necessary
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % necessary
\usepackage{minted} % Framework for code formatting
\begin{document}
\begin{quiz}{My first quiz}
    \begin{multi}[multiple]{Advanced Mode}
        Which numbers are prime?
        \item[fraction=-50] 2
        \item[fraction=50] 5
        \item[fraction=50] 7
        \item[fraction=-50] 1
        \item[fraction=-50] 6
    \end{multi}

    \begin{essay}[response required=true, response format=text]{Freitext2}
        What is missing in this class: \newline
        \begin{minted}[linenos]{java}
            public class MyTest{
                private String name;
            }
        \end{minted}
    \item
    \end{essay}


\end{quiz}
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, the minted package produces errors even if the minted block is commented out. Do you have any idea on how to use the two packages together or do you have an alternative idea on how to show minted Code in the question block.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome! I do not think that minted is compatible with `moodle.sty` at all. You could check with the author  @mgk at https://framagit.org/mattgk/moodle, but your best option, I think, is to generate the "minted" codes as independent PDFs and then include them as graphics (with `includegraphics`).

Comment: @Rmano Minted relies on the Python library pygments, which is capable of exporting HTML code. The moodle package does take advantage of this opportunity !

Answer (score 3):

Thanks Rmano for the hint to the repo. I checked it out and amazingly, minted support is in version 1.0 included. Thus, all I had to do was update my packages and now this code works:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[nostamp]{moodle}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % necessary
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % necessary
\usepackage{minted} % Framework for code formatting
\renewcommand\theFancyVerbLine{\normalsize\arabic{FancyVerbLine}}
\begin{document}

\begin{quiz}{My first quiz}
    \begin{multi}[multiple]{Advanced Mode}
        Which numbers are prime?
        \item[fraction=-50] 2
        \item[fraction=50] 5
        \item[fraction=50] 7
        \item[fraction=-50] 1
        \item[fraction=-50] 6
    \end{multi}
    \setminted{numbersep=3ex,tabsize=4,numberblanklines=false,autogobble=true,style=abap}
    \begin{VerbatimOut}{_minted-test/test.java}
        public class MyTest{
            private String name;
        }
        \end{VerbatimOut}

    \begin{essay}[response field lines=40, response required=true, response format=text, points=10]{EssayQuestion}
    \inputminted[numbers=left]{java}{_minted-test/test.java}
        \item

    \end{essay}


\end{quiz}
\end{document}
```

Comment: actually, the minted support has been there for a few versions of the Moodle package. Version 1.0 just fixes something broken due to recent changes in minted.